# Is it possible to pass a table from template to email body?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have to pass data from template to an email body. Is it possible or how can I solve this?

I have this list

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="3">
            <label>MARCA</label>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="4">
            <label>PRODUCTO</label>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="3">
            <label>PRESENT.</label>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="2">
            <label>CANT.</label>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let producto of productos">
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="3">
              <label>{{ producto.marca }}</label>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col size="4">
              <label>{{ producto.producto }}</label>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col size="3">
              <label>{{ producto.presentacion }}</label>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col size="2">
              <label{{ producto.cantidad }}</label>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
      </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

[image: Result of the table]

And I want to pass this table to an email body, I'm using social sharing plugin to send the email:

```
this.socialSharing.canShareViaEmail().then(() => {
        this.socialSharing.shareViaEmail(
        'HERE COMES THE BODY AND I WANT TO PUT HERE THE ion-list',
        'Subject',
        ['example@hotmail.com']).then(() => {
            // Success!
        });
      });

This is the plugin example!
this.socialSharing.shareViaEmail('Body', 'Subject', ['recipient@example.org']).then(() => {
  // Success!
})
```

Answer (score 1):

So I don't think it is as simple as just outputting the converted ion component table into an email friendly html template. But you most certainly can create a helper script that will do that for you.

If you know the structure of the email beforehand, its very easy to create a simple script that will iterate through your items and populate them into the email template you desire.

I'm not going to write all the code but here's a quick idea of something I've done in the past:

```
createHtmlTableRow = (producto) => `
          <tr>
            <td size="3">
              <label>${producto.marca}</label>
            </td>
            <td size="4">
              <label>${producto.producto}</label>
            </td>
            <td size="3">
              <label>${producto.presentacion}</label>
            </td>
            <td size="2">
              <label>${producto.cantidad}</label>
            </td>
          </tr>`;

createHtmlTemplate = (products) => {
    let emailTemplate: string = `<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <label>MARCA</label>
          </th>
          <th>
            <label>PRODUCTO</label>
          </th>
          <th>
            <label>PRESENT.</label>
          </th>
          <th>
            <label>CANT.</label>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>`;

    for (let product of products) {
        emailTemplate += this.createHtmlTableRow(product);
    }

    emailTemplate += '</tbody></table>';

    return emailTemplate;
}

...

this.socialSharing.canShareViaEmail().then(() => {
    this.socialSharing.shareViaEmail(this.createHtmlTemplate(producto), 'Subject', ['example@hotmail.com']).then(() => {
        // Success!
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, after a lot of research I noticed that some email client (for example Gmail) doesn't support html tags like table so it's not possible to do what I want.